# How to get count of nulls/nan of a column having datatype as timestamp in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column called **createdtime** with datatype as timestamp, I want to find the count of rows where the createdtime is null or empty or nan.

I tried below method but I am getting error and was unable to get through it

```
#Find count for selected columns
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,isnan,when,count
df_Columns=["createdtime"]
df.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df_Columns]
   ).show()
```

Below is the error:
[image]

Comment: What error do you get? The code works well to me, so you'll have to provide the error in order to debug.

Comment: @ZygD Added the error screenshot, Sorry I forgot to add it previously

Comment: You cannot have NaN in a column of timestamp type, which is long internally, only NULL.

Comment: @HristoIliev, So I should remove "isnan(c) |" right?

Comment: Yea, it seems you'll be fine if you removed that clause.

Answer (score 1):

Count of Missing values of all columns in dataframe in pyspark using isnan() Function

Count of null values of dataframe in pyspark using isNull() Function

Count of null values of single column in pyspark using isNull() Function

Count of Missing values of single column in pyspark using isnan() Function .

Suppose data frame name is df1 then could would be to find count of null values would be

Get count of both null and missing values in pyspark.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count, col
df1.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in 
df1.columns]).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isnull` and `sum` functions like in this snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

some_data = np.arange(100, 200, 10)
createdtime = np.array([np.nan, *[11, 13, 14, 5], np.nan, *[18, 19, 26, 12]])
df = pd.DataFrame({"some_data": some_data, "createdtime": createdtime})
print(df.createdtime.isnull().sum())
```

`df.createdtime.isnull().sum()` can help you with your problem. I think your dataframe is not pandas.DataFrame type, there is a [function in pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html#:%7E:text=pandas%2Don%2DSpark%20DataFrame%20and%20Spark%20DataFrame%20are%20virtually%20interchangeable.&text=However%2C%20note%20that%20a%20new,as%20an%20index%20when%20possible.) to convert it.